# Can I enter Colombia with an expired passport if I possess a second nationality?

Tags: uk-citizens, dual-nationality, colombian-citizens

Hi i have tried on several occasions to get in touch with the colombian consulate in london and to no avail. My british passport is an electronic passport but my colombian one is not. I plan to travel to colombia in a months time. Is it possible to travel with my british passport to colombia and my non electronical colombian passport which states it expires on the 2017? i have my colombian cedula identity card up to date. Will i have problems entering Colombia?? please someone help and advise

Comment: I think you should only show them your Colombian documents and I can't really imagine they would not allow their citizen in.  I would think that even an expired passport should be good enough to enter your country, so that you can apply for a new one "from home".

Comment: It is now 2016.  Your passport expires in 2017.  Your passport is therefore valid.  Am I missing something?

Comment: phoog  its not an electronic or has the barcode to scan. its just a standard Colombian passport they say on the consulate website its now void. Im wondering if i can travel with my electronic British passport surely that should be ok right? Ive heard that the Colombian authorities can be quite funny even send you back  if you enter with your British passport or any other passport  being a Colombian citizen. Im based in London and the majority of my family live in Colombia i must travel due to bereavement in the family.

Comment: Grzenio i don't think any country would allow you in their country even if you are a citizen with an invalid passport but i have booked an appt to get an electronically Colombian one with the london consulate which is in June the dates are ridiculous there is nothing available sooner. i could ask if i could get it done in colombia but its still no guarantee they will let me in.

Comment: @Grzenio Not all countries allow citizens to re-enter with expired or invalid documentation. For instance, India is (in)famous for refusing to allow citizens with expired passports to enter the country.

Comment: Vanessa: Is your passport machine readable?  That is, does it look like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/ColombianBiometricPassportInside.jpg), with two rows of data at the bottom of the ID page? If so, it is still valid even if it is not an e-passport. See http://bu.com.co/en/newsandpublications/300.

Comment: Please check this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45265/colombian-entering-colombia-on-day-of-colombian-passport-expiry-date-could-i-be?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Colombia has a law requiring dual nationals to enter Colombia with their Colombian passports:

> **Nota:** De conformidad con el Artículo 22 de la Ley 43 de 1993, el ciudadano  colombiano que posea doble nacionalidad, en el territorio colombiano, se someterá a la Constitución Política y a las leyes de la República. En consecuencia, su ingreso y permanencia en el territorio, así como su salida, deberán hacerse siempre en calidad de colombiano, por lo tanto deberá tener pasaporte colombiano para el ingreso y la salida del territorio colombiano.

Source: http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/tramites_servicios/pasaportes

> Annotation: In accordance to Article 22 of Law No. 43 of 1993, Colombian citizens with dual nationality will be subject, in Colombian territory, to the Constitution and Laws of the Republic. Therefore the inmigration and emigration processes must always be done in his/her status as Colombian citizens and a current valid Colombian Passport is required.

Source: http://www.cancilleria.gov.co/en/procedures_services/passports

To comply with this law, then it seems that your only option is to be persistent in trying to make contact with the Colombian consulate.  If you don't have enough time for an ordinary application, you might be able to file an emergency application.

Or, depending on your passport, it may not actually be invalid.  Machine-readable passports continue to be valid, according to http://bu.com.co/en/newsandpublications/300.

It is interesting to note that the English translation says "current valid" but as far as my limited Spanish skills can ascertain, there is no such condition in the Spanish text.

Comment: What is immigration going to do if the citizen's passport is expired? Deport them?

Comment: @JonathanReez I do not know.  See [Michael Hampton's comment about India](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61914/can-i-enter-colombia-with-an-expired-passport-if-i-possess-a-second-nationality/61933?noredirect=1#comment129666_61914).

Comment: but India doesn't allow double citizenship, while Colombia does. It's therefore illegal to travel to India with a passport from a different country, which is a whole different issue.

Comment: @JonathanReez but it's not necessarily illegal to travel to India with an expired Indian passport.  The UK allows British citizens to travel to the UK with expired UK passports, for example.